# How to calculate combustion temp?

Tags: fuel, calculation, performance, hypergolics, hydrogen-peroxide

I was reading about a propellant combination using ethanolamine(19.9% propellant fraction w/ 1% Copper Chloride) and 90% HTP(80.1%). I am trying to design a *hypothetical* engine around the propellant, but am unable to find the combustion temperature as it is quite niche. I would like to know how exactly you could go about doing this, preferably without any software. I imagine it is even more challenging as you'd have to also account for the h2o2 decomposition.

[Investigation of Hypergolic Fuels with Hydrogen Peroxide](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/255266862_Investigation_of_Hypergolic_Fuels_with_Hydrogen_Peroxide)

Comment: The industry standard is the NASA Computer program CEA (Chemical Equilibrium with Applications) calculates chemical equilibrium compositions and properties of complex mixtures. Applications include assigned thermodynamic states, theoretical rocket performance, Chapman-Jouguet detonations, and shock-tube parameters for incident and reflected shocks 
https://www1.grc.nasa.gov/research-and-engineering/ceaweb/       But that is software.

Comment: A comment on the old answer links to https://cearun.grc.nasa.gov/ which may be the same software mentioned by @tckosvic . But yes, that is software.